# How to solve "app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug" in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, build

Here I am getting the following issue while I try to run the app after updating build version.Even I tried many relevant solution which was answered in StackOverflow. But noting works.

Even I did the following :

- clean the project,
- Invalidate Cache & Restart,
- Delete app/build/intermediates everything.
- android.enableD8.desugaring = true (or) android.enableD8=true

Nothing works.The issue is as follows,

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with
>
> main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments
>
> {@PROJECT_NAME\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args5924990363826958654}

Your answer is more valuable. Please support me

Comment: compileOptions {
    //sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    //targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

Comment: why does this solve the problem @ibadurrahman?

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: Actually already I have used the line that you mentioned. @ibadurrahman

Comment: Can you upload an example project with the same characteristics (and the same error) on github? Additionally you need to specify the AS version you are using